# cannot write script in sting c#

Tags: c#, javascript

can someone please tell me why I cant do this

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string jj = "</script>";
}
</script>
```

ends up not being a string and it breaks up my ending tags in the aspx page.

Comment: string jj = "<//script>";

Comment: As Hoang said, just simply use literals. You can also use `@` like this `@"</script>"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your string, either `"<//script>"` or `@"</string>"`.